# running speech recognition python script at start up

Tags: python

I have a python script that listens out for certain keywords and performs an action such as rebooting the pc or updating the pc, I put the python file in application auto start (mx linux) but doesn't seem to be working, when I run the file it will work fine but I would like to run it in the background when my computer starts up, thank you.

```
import speech_recognition as s_r
import subprocess
import time
import os


r = s_r.Recognizer()
my_mic_device = s_r.Microphone(device_index=7)

def start():
    response = None
    audio = None
    subprocess.Popen("clear")
    print("---READY---")

    with my_mic_device as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=2)

    try:
        response = r.recognize_google(audio)
        response = response.lower()
    except s_r.UnknownValueError:
        print("Unknown value")
    except s_r.RequestError:
        print("Request error")

    if response == "firefox":
        subprocess.Popen("firefox")
        start()
    elif response == "off":
        os.system("sudo poweroff")
    elif response == "reboot":
        os.system("sudo reboot")
    elif response == "terminal":
        subprocess.Popen("terminator")
        start()
    else:
        start()

start()
```

Comment: Consider adding the Python script to systemd, to run on startup.

Comment: is there any other way to run from start up as mx linux doesn't use systemd, I tried crontab but it didnt work